# Can we develop with ros/stage only in Python

Tags: ros, python, simulation, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I want to simulate in 2D a mobile robot with simple dynamics in a dynamic environment using Python.

1. Do you think that ROS/stage is a good choice for this.
2. How steep is the learning curve.
3. Can I develop everything in Python only.(I'n no c++)
4. If c++ is unavoidable, will it be sufficient to get the basics quickly.
5. What about Gazebo, will it be interesting or unnecessary to use in my case.

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59523/can-we-develop-with-ros/stage-only-in-python./) by [amine23](https://answers.ros.org/users/3879/amine23/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2013-03-29

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. Both are good choices. About the "dynamic", if you mean to support linear and angular acceleration and brake constraints, that it's not supported in the current brach of stage while it is supported in Gazebo. In any case I work with a modified version of stage which support dynamic constraints. You can take a look: http://rtc-us-ros-pkg.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/rtc-us-ros-pkg/trunk/rntl/stage_rep/
2. Using ROS fluently requires some time. However you'll be happy when you learn because you will be able to use tons of software and you will "speak" the same technical language that many developers and researchers.
3. Stage and Gazebo can be controlled using rostopics, rosservices and rosparameters. That means that you can use python to control such simulators.
   In other words you don't need to know the C++ APIs of Stage or Gazebo to work with them. You can just use python, topics, services and parameters.
4. If you are a beginer, start with Python. It is enough to try to learn ROS, learning c++ simultaneously may be horrible.
5. As I said, both are good choices.

---

Originally posted by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) with karma: 2982 on 2013-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [amine23](https://answers.ros.org/users/3879/amine23/) on 2013-03-29**:
Thanks! Actually, I meant environments involving moving obstacles, but the robot should also operate under dynamic constraints though.

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2013-03-29**:
If you want to consider moving obstacles in stage you have to program manually more capabilities to stageros. That means to know c++ and the Stage API (I do that when I want to add more capabilities to the Stage). On the other hand you can handle moving obstacles in gazebo from ROS topics :-)

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-03-29**:
Stage is a good simulator, but beware: it tends to release incompatible API changes about once a year. Gazebo is more actively developed and supported right now.

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2013-03-30**:
That's right. But from the point of view of the stageros node interface the simulator is enough stable. The problem would appear if the stage package were not going to be mainained anymore.